# Find WSDL in Web Service example using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

Im doing a simple WebService based on this youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3w6LBl8E-8

This tutorial deploys the service using the built in java application/publisher to the localhost (i suppose..)

The only way i can see (in the video) to access the generated **WSDL** is through the web browser.

Is the generated WSDL not saved somewhere in the eclipse folder structure of the project?
Is it not supposed to be?
If not, how can i save it there somewhere?

Thank you very much

Comment: wsdl file will be generated inside WEB-INF/wsdl folder. During web service creation in the wizard itself you have the option to enable generation of wsdl.

Comment: Hey! Thank you, i was able to do it now. Very much thanks!